# In-App Purchase - How to restore only one product

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

My question is about StoreKit. If I have more than one in-app purchase is it possible to restore only ONE product? Because now when I click I get all of the possible in-app purchases even if I bought only one of them.

I'm using the code by Kilo Loco.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3hJ0rY1NNw&t=2546s

```
class IAPService: NSObject {

private override init() {}
static let shared = IAPService()

var products = [SKProduct]()
let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()

func getProducts() {
    let products: Set = [IAPProducts.nonConsumable.rawValue,  IAPProducts.nonConsumable2.rawValue]
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: products)
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
    paymentQueue.add(self)
}

func purchase(product: IAPProducts) {
    guard let productToPurchase = products.filter({ $0.productIdentifier == product.rawValue }).first else { return }
    let payment = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)
    paymentQueue.add(payment)
}

func restorePurchases() {
    print("restore purchases")
    paymentQueue.restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
```

}

```
extension IAPService: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    products = response.products
    for product in response.products {
        print(product.localizedTitle)
    }
}
```

}

```
extension IAPService: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        print(transaction.transactionState.status(), transaction.payment.productIdentifier)

        if transaction.transactionState.rawValue == 1
        {
            if ViewController.paketas == 1 {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(11, forKey: "pack1")
            }
            if ViewController.paketas == 2 {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(12, forKey: "pack2")
            }
        }

        if transaction.transactionState.rawValue == 3
        {
            if ViewController.paketas == 1 {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(11, forKey: "pack1")
            }
            if ViewController.paketas == 2 {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(12, forKey: "pack2")
            }
        }

        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchasing: break
        default: queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
extension SKPaymentTransactionState {
func status() -> String {
    switch self {
    case .deferred: return "deferred"
    case .failed: return "failed"
    case .purchased: return "purchased"
    case .purchasing: return "purchasing"
    case .restored: return "restored"
    }
}
```

}

Any information or advice would be really helpful.

Comment: The code you've posted is missing a lot of required code to handle the call to `paymentQueue.restoreCompletedTransactions()`. And why would you only want to restore one product? You should restore all products a user has purchased.

Comment: You have four types of purchases you can make - "pay up front", "non-consumable", "consumable" and "subscription". First off, *you* are missing that info in your question. Second, for the latter two, I'm sure there's ways to insure if the purchase has expired or been consumed, they aren't restored. But for the first two? No! Why would you wish to do anything *but* restore what the consumer bought?

Comment: @rmaddy Imagine. There are 3 types of goods in the application which you can buy. Apple, Banana, Pineapple. You only buy Apple. Then you click restore and then you get all of them even if you purchased only Apple. This is the problem I'm facing right now.

Comment: @dfd I have only non-consumable products. Sorry if my question was not clear enough. As I said, the problem is that when the user clicks restore then he gets ALL of the products my application has even if he bought only one of them.

Comment: Your code looks good - at least similar to mine. What makes you believe it restores all products, including those not purchased? There are definitely some quirky behaviors with sandbox testing. I'm trying to use a third party open-source framework called `IAPKit`. Here's a comment they have: *"leaving this here for testing as it's a total pain to work with sandbox accounts.  Once a product has been purchased on an account, it is there forever."* Any chance you're seeing this?

Comment: @dfd Actually it's pretty funny but I bought package from myself (lol). So, I tried this in real world with real apple ID.

Comment: So, to get this straight, you have... apples, bananas, and pineapples for sale - and you bought apples only. Now when you run your code for "restore purchases" (which looks good to me) you suddenly own all three? My plan for my next (soon-to-be-submitted) app is to use IAPKit for a free trial, with both standard and pro versions. I like how they handle receipts. I'll keep this in mind while testing next week and comment on what I see.

Comment: BTW, don't feel bad. My one app with a "tasteful" watermark was so underwhelming in conversions I also bought the "remove watermark" IAP just to prove to myself that I coded things right! :-)

Comment: @dfd Yes, you're right. This is exactly what happens with restore purchases. :)